# Detect when memory moves in an external .NET process?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I wrote the indie MMORPG, [Pixel Champions](http://www.pixelchampions.com). I'm wondering, [after seeing this *trainer* appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eofr9.png), if it's possible for an external process to reliably read my game-client's memory. I know that users can `PInvoke` `ReadProcessMemory` to read whatever memory location they desire, but in a .NET application that memory moves around, and so the results wouldn't be very reliable.

Is there a way a user could know when a memory location was moved in an external .NET process? Specifically, is there any APIs exposed by the .NET GC that would allow an external application to be notified when a memory pointer needed to be updated?

Comment: I don't think so, is it possible that you didn't sign the assemblies? That he replaced a library and maybee did some reflection?  (nice game, looks like a mixup of minecraft/runescape classic)

Comment: .NET is a bytecode runtime environment, so that makes it rather easy to debug.  Not sure if/how you would prevent others from looking at your running assemblies via debugging techniques.

Comment: @ChrisO Recompiling a decompiled obfuscated .NET assembly, to my knowledge, still isn't capable of being done easily. By that I mean there's no tools readily available that will make that task straightforward.

Comment: Like @JeroenvanLangen said, be sure to sign the assemblies.  Somebody can still use ILDasm to peek at the IL, but won't be able to use ILAsm to swap in their modified version of your assemblies.  Obfuscation will only slow down the understanding process of looking at the IL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attacker can use the CLR Profiling API to receive callbacks when the GC moves objects around, which can be used to reliably track moving references.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361123.aspx